# pipenv python version in Colab

Tags: python, linux, google-colaboratory

I have installed pipenv in Colab.
I have python3.10 in /usr/local/bin/python and python3.9 in /usr/bin/python3.
I run the following command:

```
!pip install pipenv
!pipenv --python /usr/local/bin/python
!pipenv sync --dev
```

Then when I run:

```
!pipenv run python --version
```

Instead of printing Python 3.10.6
it prints Python 3.9.1, i.e. Python3.9.1 exists inside pip.
How do I resolve this error?
I want Python 3.10